# c# gridview in webform with field is combobox selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to create a gridview in webform in c#.net, this gridview should have field data populated from a table from SQLserver. This gridview must be able to be edited and save back to database.
1 of the field(the second field) in the gridview must be a combobox with the current record data in it by default, unless someone click the combobox and change the data.

Can someone show me how to do it?

I have used a sqldatasource bind to the gridview, it work fine, but I could not customise the second field to be a combobox with list of data to be selected.
I want to know how to achieve this, it is possible to maintain existing condition ie with sqldatasource automatic bind to it and just change the 2nd field?
Or I need to manually use code to bind all the data myself or something like this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, I watched the youtube below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YB2pe_C2Tbg

Comment: please also describe the solution, don't post only the source